# Having trouble setting up Android SSH tunnel with port forwarding (x-post /r/ssh)

Tags: ssh, firefox-for-android, proxy

I'm trying to log into an SSH server in such a way that I can securely visit websites on my Android phone. I have done the following:

1. Set up port forwarding for SSH server xyz.org, port 8080 on VX Connectbot (I did this with "Edit port forwards"->"Add port forward")
2. Logged into xyz.org on VX Connectbot
3. In Firefox, set:

   - network.proxy.socks=127.0.0.1
   - network.proxy.socks_port=8080
   - network.proxy.socks_remote_dns=true

But when I go to whatsmyip.org, the WHOIS lookup shows my cell phone provider, when it should be showing the SSH server. What am I doing wrong?

Is it possible that the SSH server is allowing me to log in, but refusing port forwarding requests? How would I test that?

Or have I incorrectly configured Firefox or VX Connectbot? Or maybe there's something else I have to do in my Connectbot session to start the port forwarding?

Reddit post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ssh/comments/6r1162/having_trouble_setting_up_android_ssh_tunnel_with/)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a different SSH server, and setting Firefox config as follows:

- network.proxy.type=1